# VBA Pivot check

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a VBA project, which is expected to search for a value (Let's call it "X") in Pivot table first column. Once found it would look for value "A" **and** "B" against ("X") in next column. If it fails it would look for value "M" **and** "N" **and** "O" in second column as that of "A" against same "X" value.

The success criteria is against "X" it either finds "A" **And** "B" **OR** "M" **And** "N" **and** "O". Upon failing it needs to go to next sheet and paste "X".

The same operation is to be repeated for X ranging from 1 to 750, which are listed in previous sheet of this workbook.

This will help me a big time, any help is greatly appreciated :).

Comment: I think it'd be easiest with a loop through each row, with five flags, one for each option ABMNO. Every time it finds an X then check for A,B,M,N,O in the 2nd column. If you have a lot of rows in the pivot table then filter it so all instance of X are at the top and it only needs to loop through until the cell its checking is no longer X.

Comment: The logic seems perfect, could you please help me with the VBA code part as well.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works, yo

```
Dim A As Boolean
Dim B As Boolean
Dim M As Boolean
Dim N As Boolean
Dim O As Boolean

Dim successCriteria As Boolean
Dim lastROW As Long
Dim i As Long

With ActiveSheet

    lastROW = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastROW
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value2 = "X" Then
            Select Case .Cells(i, 2).Value2
                Case "A"
                    A = True
                Case "B"
                    B = True
                Case "M"
                    M = True
                Case "N"
                    N = True
                Case "O"
                    O = True
            End Select
        End If
    Next i

End With
```